Azure data factory - Generate custom Guid and copy to SQL table
I need to generate a unique Guid which contains only numeric and of length 20, for every row in the table.
Currently, I am running one lookup activity (name - FetchIDs) to run the Stored procedure. Output of the lookup activity is as shown below
 {
   “count”: 2,
   “value”: [
      {
        “name”: “Test”,
        “ID”: 12345,
        “City”: “City A”,
        “State”: “State A”
      },
      {
        “name”: “Test2”,
        “ID”: 23456,
        “City”: “City B”,
        “State”: “State B”
      }
    ]
 }

Above lookup output might have N number of rows. I would need to add a logic to create a unique custom Guid for each row in above field and then copy this over to another SQL table (named - OutputTable)
I tried using inbuilt guid(‘N’) to generate the unique GUID. However; it was alphanumeric. I wanted to create a unique numerical GuID Of length 20 for each row, before copying it over to the SQL table.
Tried a few options. But, have not been able to come up with the way which can solve it.

As your ask is generating only numeric codes, you cannot use uuid() function in dataflow; you can use random function in mapping dataflow.But it would generate 16 length numeric character so you can concatenate 2 random numerics to create a 20 length variant.
Also you can use rand function directly in SQL database itself as default column value

When you say use directly in Sql database itself.
Are you referring to using copy activity to copy from stored procedure to temp table. And then using another sql query to copy from temp table to real table where I need extra columns to be copied, and add the rand function as part of that?
What would be the best way to ensure each row gets this unique  random ID of its own added when copying from stored procedure to sql table

Nandan - Any thoughts on this?
